# How to import Python package (Pytorch-neat) that is not installable from pip/conda repositories?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch

I am trying to used Pytorch-neat package https://github.com/uber-research/PyTorch-NEAT but I don't understand the workflow of using it. I already installed python-neat package and I can import it using `import neat` in my Jupyter notebook. But what should I do with Pytroch-neat code? There is no pytorch-neat package in Conda or pip repositories, so, I guess that this Pytroch-neat code is not compiled and distributed as the Python package for Jupyter notebook. But what should I do with this code? E.g. sample script contains the code:

```
import neat

from pytorch_neat.multi_env_eval import MultiEnvEvaluator
```

So - neat is package and I am importing it. But how to understand the from clause? Should I load Pytroch-neat scripts somehow in the previous cells of my notebook and then I can call this from clause? Or maybe I should compile Pytroch-neat package locally and install it from local repository and import it similarly to neat package. But if so, why the examples use from clause?

I am starting to use Python and I am greatly confused with all of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import `from pytorch_neat` you have to clone the repository and manually copy directory [`pytorch_neat`](https://github.com/uber-research/PyTorch-NEAT/tree/master/pytorch_neat) into your `site-packages` (or any directory in `sys.path`).